# Definite complex integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \lambda e^{(ik-\lambda)x} dx$ from characteristical function of exponential distribuition

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-theory

How can I show that the upper limit of this integral is zero? I'm confused on how to apply infinity only in the real component.

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \lambda e^{(ik-\lambda)x} dx$$

Comment: The integral is $(1-ik/\lambda)^{-1}$ if $\Re\lambda>0$. What do you mean by the "upper limit" of it?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\lambda$ is real and $\lambda >0$ as you work with a exponential distribution, then 
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_0^{R} \lambda e^{(ik-\lambda)x}dx=\lim_{R\to\infty}\bigg[\frac{\lambda}{ik-\lambda}e^{(ik-\lambda)x}\bigg]_0^{R}=\lim_{R\to\infty}\bigg[\frac{\lambda}{ik-\lambda}e^{ikR}e^{-\lambda R}-\frac{\lambda}{ik-\lambda}\bigg]$$
Now observe $|e^{ikR}e^{-\lambda R}|=e^{-\lambda R}$ , since $|e^{ikR}|=1$. Finally argue with $\lim _{R\to \infty}e^{-\lambda R}= 0$, that
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}e^{ikR}e^{-\lambda R}=0$$
hence

$$\int_0^{\infty} \lambda e^{(ik-\lambda)x}dx=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-ik}$$

Comment: YES! I forgot about this, since I used a long time ago. Thanks a lot, man.